# Facebook JS SDK: How to logout app-only from Facebook as of now?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Over the last years Facebook changed their API several times.
I started to use them today (specifically Javascript SDK): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript).

I login by:

```
    FB.init({
      appId      : appVariables.FacebookOauth2Parameters.appId,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
```

which works flawlessly.

My problem is **how to logout the user from my app only (i.e. removing my app from the user account)**.

In fact

```
FB.logout
```

can be used, it works but **it also logs out the user from Facebook itself**.

I tried by:

```
                var revokeUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next='+ appVariables.FacebookOauth2Parameters.appId +'&access_token=' + $scope.oAuthToken;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: revokeUrl,
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(response) {

                    },
                    error: function(e) {

                });
```

but despite the "success" branch executes, **my app isn't removed from the Facebook account I used for my tests.**

Any clue?

Comment: This is how the SDK designed. Calling logout will log the user out as well.

Comment: that was clear. my question is : is there a workaround?